# console.log always prints the highest index in a for loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jestjs

Below is the simple jest test block in JavaScript, under the `describe` I've written a simple `test` to print the current index of the loop (until 5) of which it is put in. But the result is always `Test 5`

```
describe("Hello", async ()=>{
    for(var i=0; i<5; ++i){
        test(``Test ${i}``, async ()=>{
            await console.debug("Test "+ i);
        });
    }
});
```

Can someone please clarify, how does it work?

Comment: generally this is because your `for` finishes before... and then `async` takes the value of `i` after that... you need to pass `i` to `async` function as a parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Use `let` instead of `var`, let will preserve the scope for each `async` call. So in each loop, new values of `i` will be passed to your method and those values will stay preserved. In the case of `var` the variable `i` will be `function` scoped (that function being the one you use as callback in `describe()`) so when your `asyn` method resolves, you will see the value of `i` which exists inside your callback, since the loop would already have ended the value would be `5`.

```js
for(let i=0; i<5; ++i){
       // dummy async method
       setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(i)
       }, 2000)
    }
```

Comment: @FlashThunder: I don't understand, how?? I know, we can definitely pass the value of `i` to each `function` call but if I pass a block scoped variable in each loop won't the variable's value stay preserved even if loop finishes??

Comment: @FlashThunder: I didn't change the meaning after edit, I just elaborated my original answer

Comment: I remove all my comments and quit. Probably didn't notice the "dummy" method.